# Есть ли предикативный центр в предложении с ирреальной модальностью?

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения

Скажите, пожалуйста, обладает ли такое предложение предикативностью?

*Приятель, нельзя ли убавить громкость?*

Является ли **убавить** предикативным центром?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Приятель, нельзя ли убавить громкость?*

Предикативная основа выражена составным глагольным сказуемым ***нельзя ли убавить***

Предикативная основа есть у любого предложения, иначе это будет не предложение, а сочетание.